# CSS Container Height

Tags: css, css-float

I'm struggling with a sidebar height.

My container is now showing the correct height (that of the content inside), but my sidebar that should be using 100% of that height is still not appearing.

I've implemented float clearing (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) but the sidebar's still not appearing.

I'm sure this is a simple one for you pros, any tips appreciated!

Thanks,

Tom

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tomperkins/wy52B/

Comment: dupicate from same person ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563946/css-container-height/4564061#4564061

Comment: @jondavidjohn: Try reading both questions again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sidebar to

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

You'll also need to change the container to `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jQuery:

```
var h = $(".sidebar").parent().height();
$(".sidebar").height(h);
```