# Bootstrap grid system within ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to format the results of an ng-repeat directive using bootstrap's grid system so that each item returned occupies 6 out of the 12 columns available. It works fine, but there's a problem with the styling.  This is the HTML:

```
<div class="bestof card col-lg-12 col-md-8">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>Best of {{dest.name}}</h1>

        <div class="col-lg-6" ng-repeat="best in bestHotels | limitTo: 2 track by $index">
                <img class="best_thumbnail" ng-src="{{best.thumbnail}}"/>
                <p>{{best.description}}</p>
        </div> 

    </div> <!-- inner -->
</div> <!-- bestof -->
```

And the CSS:

```
.inner {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    border-right: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #c1c1c1;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
```

Basically, the *inner* div seems to just stop before enclosing ng-repeat, so I have a bottom border right after my `<h1>`, but before any of the content actually displays. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a JSFiddle or a Codepen? This question will likely require access to more of your CSS (i.e. `bestof` and `card` classes).

Comment: Also, does it render correctly without `ng-repeat` if you just placed two divs side-by-side?

Comment: where is the `.row` that should be parent of any `.col` element ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Container div ignores height of floated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442934/container-div-ignores-height-of-floated-elements)

Comment: @Pevara Thanks! Didn't think skipping on a .row would be much of a problem, but I was clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to make sure the `.inner` DIV has `overflow:auto` like this..

```
.inner {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    border-right: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #c1c1c1;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Demo:** http://bootply.com/3zT91GNLNI

***EDIT*** - A better solution as suggested by @Pevara would be to make `inner` a `row`..

http://bootply.com/mv0T7iZHrX

Comment: @Skelly Thanks, both methods did the trick, I'll stick with using the .row class then :)